# AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor override to remove options - issues

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I've code directly from this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs

...but have an issue when trying to assign an ID to the control:

```
                <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 5px">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEditor" runat="server">
                        <custom:CertDescEditor Width="100%" Height="200px" runat="server" ID="edDesc" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
```

I get this error:
The type or namespace name 'MyControls' could not be found in the global namespace

Page registration:
<%@ Register Namespace="MyControls" TagPrefix="custom" %>

Code in App_Code folder:

using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor;

namespace MyControls
{
public class CertDescEditor : Editor
{
protected override void FillTopToolbar()
{
TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Italic());
TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Underline());
TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.StrikeThrough());
}

```
    protected override void FillBottomToolbar()
    {
        BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.DesignMode());
        BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.PreviewMode());
        BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.HtmlMode());
    }
}
```

}

I've tried all sorts of namespaces etc, and nothing will work. Eventuall tried to proceed with no ID and iterated through controls to get/set the object. This works in localhost but fails on deployment, static invalid server tag.

Any ideas? Thank you